# How is this sum passed into the correct column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am debugging some code and I have a couple questions that I can’t figure out.

Below I have a sum of 8 different credit values and they are named `cashCredits`. Are they being passed into the column `totalCredits` even though they are named `cashCredits`? Do they need to be named `totalCredits` where they are summed instead of `cashCredits`?

I am almost positive this is working the way it should, but I am still learning SQL Server. Any help is greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance.

```
Create Table #Credits
(
    empId varchar(8), 
    [date] datetime, 
    [storeId] varchar(5), 
    totalCredits money
)

insert into #Credits(empId, [date], [storeId], totalCredits)
   Select 
      credit.[empId], credit.[date], credit.[storeId],
      (Select credit.value1 + credit.value2 + credit.value3 + credit.value4 + credit.value5 + credit.value6 + credit.value7 + credit.value8) as cashCredits
   From 
      #arCredits credit
```

Comment: yes, they should be named totalCredits

Comment: I would try to avoid using *reserved SQL keywords* like `date` as table or column names .... use something more meaningful, less confusing

Comment: Since you say you are new to sql server you might want to read up on normalization. Column names like value1, value2 indicate some normalization would likely help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aliases of the columns in your select are irrelevant, as they are inserted based in the column order in the "INSERT INTO" clause.  For example,

```
INSERT  INTO #Credits
        ( empId ,
          [date] ,
          [storeId] ,
          totalCredits
        )
        SELECT  credit.[empId] AS a ,
                credit.[date]  AS b,
                credit.[storeId] AS c,
                ( SELECT    credit.value1 + credit.value2 + credit.value3
                            + credit.value4 + credit.value5 + credit.value6
                            + credit.value7 + credit.value8
                ) AS d
        FROM    #arCredits credit
```

works exactly the same as

```
INSERT  INTO #Credits
        ( empId ,
          [date] ,
          [storeId] ,
          totalCredits
        )
        SELECT  credit.[empId] AS four ,
                credit.[date]  AS three,
                credit.[storeId] AS two,
                ( SELECT    credit.value1 + credit.value2 + credit.value3
                            + credit.value4 + credit.value5 + credit.value6
                            + credit.value7 + credit.value8
                ) AS one
        FROM    #arCredits credit
```

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as the map remains ordered, you do not need to change the name of cashCredits to totalCredits.